# How to get the WordEditor property of the currently selected email in an explorer reading pane?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I implement context menus for emails, this includes the explorer reading pane.  To get the text under the mouse at the time of a right click I use the WordEditor. I do not think there is any other way of finding out where the mouse has clicked.

```
'_olItem comes from the current selection
olInspector = CType(_olItem.GetInspector, Outlook.Inspector)
wDoc = CType(olInspector.WordEditor, Word.Document)
'then go off and work with word
```

For the Explorer reading pane is the only way to get the WordEditor by first calling GetInspector?

One reason for asking is that I see that for [Inline responses Outlook has the ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponsewordeditor) property.

My addin also listens for new inspectors

```
Private Sub oInsps_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles oInsps.NewInspector
'do something here with this inspector
End Sub
```

If I cannot avoid calling GetInspector to get the word editor then is there a property of the inspector at the time the newinspector event fires to tell me that this inspector is actually from the reading pane and from me calling GetInspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor`.

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: yep that works.  Should have found that myself.  Thank you.